# Каким образом можно найти источник зависимости в gradle?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, gradle

В проекте имеется build.gradle и libraries.gradle с огромной кучей различных зависимостей. В этом проекте используется нужная мне зависимость, условно кастомная аннотация. Я смог найти библиотеку с этой аннотацией, но не смог найти строчку в build.gradle или libraries.gradle, которая отвечает за импорт этой библиотеки. То есть она приходит в составе другой какой-то зависимости\библиотеки.

Я вижу нужную мне библиотеку в структуре проекта в блоке External libraries в Intellij IDEA. Но откуда она туда пришла - понять не могу.

Можно ли каким-то образом выяснить благодаря какой зависимости, которая описана явно в build.gradle или libraries.gradle, приходит нужная мне аннотация?

Answer (score 0):

Есть такое - просмотр дерева зависимостей
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html